# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filter'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use django-filter on my application but I get the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filter'
Below is my code base
settings.py
'''
...
'django_filter'
...
'''
I have also installed django_filter in my application.

Comment: It is `django_filters`, not `django_filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
pip install django-filter
```

and add `django_filters` in you `INSTALLED_APPS`.

[Official doc](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/install.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot I actually missed the 's' while adding it to my installed apps. 
thanks it works now

Answer (score 0):

first install django-filter using `pip install django-filter`
than add the django-filter in
`INSTALLED_APPS=[ ... django_filter ]`

Comment: duplicate answer